# Trigger for new table inserts

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables, Organisation and State(where it is). Each Organisation has a state. I would now like to implement a Integer column for the table State which keeps tracks of how many organisations are in it. Kinda like whenever a new organisation is inserted into Organisations table, update integer column in corresponding State table where org.state_id = state_id.

Is this possible using triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Glenn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043195/482758) that, all things being equal, on-demand is a better solution, but the answer is that, yes, it can be done with a trigger. Very easily.

```
CREATE TRIGGER organization_trigger_insert AFTER INSERT ON organization
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE state SET total = total + 1 WHERE NEW.state_id = state_id;
    END;

CREATE TRIGGER organization_trigger_delete BEFORE DELETE ON organization
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE state SET total = total - 1 WHERE OLD.state_id = state_id;
    END;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0959f/2)

Comment: and make sure to add the corresponding delete trigger while you're at it... :)

Comment: Given the scenario in the comment I gave Glenn, what do you think? On demand or trigger? And thanks a bunch, had a feeling it wouldn't be very hard :)

Comment: Updated with DELETE trigger. @Hasslam: I think you should try querying first and if that doesn't work out switch to triggers. "It depends."

Answer (score 2):

Rather than keeping track of a computed column, it is often preferable to just calculate what you want on demand. So if you have these two tables:

```
organization(id, name, state_id)

state(id, name)
```

A query such as the following gets the counts:

```
SELECT s.name, COUNT(*) AS organization_count
  FROM state s JOIN organization o ON (s.id = o.state_id)
  GROUP BY s.name
```

This avoids integrity issues. If you are dealing with hundreds of thousands of records or operating in a reporting environment, then you might want to consider computing the info.

Comment: Thanks for that query input, I need to dig deeper into that. Thing is that clients in my application will get how many organisation there are in each state(25 states) pretty often. This makes it important to run smooth. Thats why I rather would fetch an integer than doing long query for each state. Given the scenario, is your approach still good?

Comment: I think it is still good if you are querying those tables anyway, and if you are not dealing with, say, hundreds of thousands of organizations.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your opinion! Quail gave the most right answer even though I will go with your approach. I'm dealing with maximum 10k organisations